# SnowFlake Convert_timezone function format mapping

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

## Problem

My 24 timezone codes are like EAT, ICT, NZT and I need to use the SnowFlake Convert_timezone function to convert the American Eastern time to the timezone that the records have. But SnowFlake Convert_timezone function only supports timezone in **standard iana.org time zones format**. So what is the best way to map my 24 time zone to the right formate so that the function can work as expected?

I did not figure out how to  set up the [standard iana.org time zones database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) and how to convert my time zone code into theirs, please help! thanks in advance!

## Sample code

```
Convert_timezone('American/New_York', my_time_zone_code, my_timestamp) as normalized_time
```

## Error

```
Unknown timezone: PST
```

Comment: Can you provide an example for values in `my_time_zone_code` and `my_timestamp`?

Comment: @MikeWalton, my_time_zone_code is like EAT, ICT, PST, NZT, my my_timestamp is like 2020-05-05 12:23:22. please see Palash comments, and I need the mapping logic to make SnowFlake recognize my timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. EAT

East Africa Time, or EAT, is a time zone used in eastern Africa. The time zone is three hours ahead of UTC (UTC+03:00), which is the same as Moscow Time, Arabia Standard Time, Further-eastern European Time and Eastern European Summer Time.

Can be safely mapped with snowflake time as below

Africa/Nairobi

2. ICT

Indochina Time (ICT) is 7 hours ahead of Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). 
Iana Timezones where ICT is currently observed.

Can be safely mapped with snowflake time as

Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh
Asia/Bangkok
Asia/Phnom_Penh
Asia/Vientiane

3. NZT

Most of the time of NZT will be associated with below two zones, to covert it to snowflake standards you have to 
divide these zones based on location either one of them

- Pacific/Auckland

  Pacific/Chatham

Hope this will help

Thanks
Palash

Comment: This is exactly what I want! I've got 24 timezone codes like these, and I need to map them to 24 timezone descriptions that SnowFlake recognizes. So how can I get a full list of this mapping? I am not familiar with the terminology so the results in Google are not informative.

Comment: Hi Vincent, unfortunately we did not find any direct mapping last time when we had similar requirement . We followed the below wiki link to create our own lookup table . You need to identify the local time zone then identify the standard based on the UTC offset and finally check for the corresponding canonical timezone to map with the "TZ db name" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: Yes, I also noticed that it is very hard to map. I found an indirect way though, using my own time zone code and daylight saving indicator for each date to deal with it. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

As per Snowflake documentation currently PDT timezone is not supported.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html

However you can follow below link to set system timezone preference.

https://support.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z00007MilHISAZ/snowflake-system-timezone-preference